# Software that helps you to create a desired artistic drawing

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for a (online) software which has a library of drawings of many objects and that allows to place them as you want, stretch, scale, and rotate and in the end, create the desired picture.
Let's say something like this or even better.

I know, one can do this using google image search and photoshop, but I am searching a software that provides all these together.

[image]

Comment: Since you mention Photoshop why not just use Adobe Stock?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a google app for doing this kind of clip-art bashing... Google Drawings. Integrated web search, throw images in, some rudimentary drawing tools, shallow learning curve - free.

[How to... Google Drawings](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nzcvpQ0owWdiTks4pVqEw92S4OyJT9moGIgS1ww_uok/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Online applications are often quite basic, but these may be all you need. One that comes to mind is Vecteezy Editor, which is quite good because it's a vector image editor. Vector graphics are good because they can be resized, stretched, and rotated without destroying their quality.

There's no shortage of clip art libraries out there. Openclipart has SVGs images you can import into virtually any vector image editor. They are also free to use for any purpose you want.  All you need to do is download an SVG, then you could import the SVG into Vecteezy, which also has an integrated illustrations library of its own vector objects.